# Deploying Cloud Functions for Firebase locally. admin.initializeApp(functions.config())

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When I tried to deploy a function on my local firebase emulator, I got this error

```
ERROR: Function load error: Code could not be loaded.
ERROR: Does the file exists? Is there a syntax error in your code?
ERROR: Detailed stack trace: /home/krishna/whozoo-firebase-web/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/config.js:51
        throw new Error('Firebase config variables are not available. ' +
Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function.
    at init (/home/krishna/whozoo-firebase-web/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/config.js:51:15)
    at Object.config (/home/krishna/whozoo-firebase-web/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/config.js:29:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/krishna/whozoo-firebase-web/functions/index.js:7:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
ERROR: Error: Failed to deploy function.
    at exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/cli/controller.js:135:18)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Then I retried deploying after removing this particular line of code

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config())
```

My function is deployed successfully but when I hit the endpoint, I end up with this message

```
{"code": "app/no-app","message": "The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services."}
```

How can I solve this error?

EDIT

```
'use strict';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const register = require('./register');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config());

exports.register = functions.https.onRequest(register.registerHandler);
```

register.js

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')

cors(req, res, () => {
let requestBody = req.body;

admin.auth().createUser({
        'email': requestBody.email,
        'emailVerified': false,
        'password': requestBody.password,
        'displayName': requestBody.firstName + ' 
        ' +requestBody.lastName
    });
});
```

This is the part of register.js that I believe causes the problem. The rest of the register.js contains the response message.

Comment: Can you show a minimal index.js that causes the problem?

Comment: According to this post it is not possible yet to deploy a Firebase function locally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763951/run-firebase-cloud-functions-locally?rq=1

Comment: Edited the post to include the index.js file. @DougStevenson

Comment: You're not showing what's in the "./register" module.

Comment: I've added the register.js module. Does this error occur because admin.auth().createUser() is an API on firebase and this can't be brought down to the local emulator? @DougStevenson

Answer (score 6):

Instead of this:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config());
```

Try this:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

Also, put that line *before* you require your register module.